# How to open a URL in an app which does not have any scheme?

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app where I am supposed to open all web links. Here are the sample web links that I need to open:

- http://www.google.com
- https://www.google.com
- www.google.com

  ```
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="DeepLinkOpen"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>

      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

          <data
              android:host="*"
              android:pathPattern="/.*"
              android:scheme="http" />

          <data
              android:host="*"
              android:pathPattern="/.*"
              android:scheme="https" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```

I am able to open the first two urls because I am accepting schemes as `http` and `https`. But how do I open the third url? Even after changing the scheme, I am not able to open the above url.

```
<data
   android:host="*"
   android:pathPattern="/.*"
   android:scheme="*" />
```

Comment: try this `<data
            android:host="www.google.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/someresource/"
            android:scheme="http" />`

Comment: https://blog.jayway.com/2009/09/24/the-browsable-category-revealed/

Comment: `But how do I open the third url?`. That is no url. It is a host name.

Comment: try replacing android:pathPattern="/.*" to android:pathPattern=".*\\..*"